# Python, asyncio: decorator in class to simplify loop syntax

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-decorators

Lets consider the following example of a class containing an asyncio loop and an async coroutine:

```
import asyncio

class Async:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def function(self, word):
        print(word)
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

a=Async()
a.loop.run_until_complete(a.function("hello_world"))
```

This does work.
I would like to create a decorator so that i can simplify the syntax of the code calling `function` to

```
a.function("hello_world")
```

I tried the following:

```
class Async:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def async_loop(f):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            self.loop.run_until_complete(f(*args, **kwargs))

    @async_loop
    async def function(self, word):
        print(word)
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

a=Async()
a.function("hello_world")
```

At that point i receive the error: `'NoneType' object is not callable`. - I also tried to have the decorator function outside of the class, but i got the same error. I'm not sure whether the decorator function best stands inside the claass (as a method) or outside.
I'm quite new to python so Asyncio, decorator, and decorators in classes are still quite confusing for me. Any good soul would have an idea how to do that code correctly?

Comment: You have committed one of the Classic Blunders. `async_loop` has to return `decorated`.

Comment: @PaulMcG ok yes - now i am receiving other errors relative to `self.loop` it is still super confusing how to do a decorator in a class for me, so help here would be hugely appreciated as weel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decorators inside classes are a mess because `self` has to creep in everywhere.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
import asyncio

class Async:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def async_loop(f):
        def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.loop.run_until_complete(f(self, *args, **kwargs))
        return decorated

    @async_loop
    async def function(self, word):
        print(word)
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

a=Async()
a.function("hello_world")
```

You can make it more "selfless" if you just declare the event loop inside async_loop, or even better, declare the decorator outside of the class:

```
def async_loop(f):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        loop.run_until_complete(f(*args, **kwargs))
    return decorated

class Async:
    @async_loop
    async def function(self, word):
        print(word)
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

a=Async()
a.function("hello_world")
```

So now it starts to raise the question, "why is this in a class in the first place?" And another question, "isn't there a decorator out there that does this already?"

Comment: Awesome thx. Why doesnt `async_loop()` need to be `async_loop(self,f)` as well? Is it still considered to be a method of the class Async?

Comment: Good question. As defined it is still a bound method to the Async instance, and what I call "f" should really be "self".  Decorators inside classes should probably be staticmethods, leading one to think "maybe decorators inside classes isn't such a great idea. See my edits.

Comment: Do you know of a decorator that does that already? I looked a bit but havent found any..

Comment: And yeah I am not sure it should be part of the class... It was a bit hard to decipher the pro and the cons before i knew the solution.. And still not certain whether should be in or out now actually! The loop is best outside the function as in my real life code it is used by multiple functions.. So only using 1 loop for all of them.. Although the gain is not so clear now that you point it out..

Comment: Still, this was an interesting exercise - I am still getting used to asyncio myself, and your post helped clarify some things for me.

Comment: why does when I try to return and assign `a.function("hello_world")` to a variable it return `None`?